# Why use interfaces

Tags: interface

I see the benefit of interfaces, to be able to add new implementations via contract.

I dont see following problem:
Imagine you have interface DB with method "startTransaction".
Everything is fine you implement it in MySQL, PostgreSQL. But tomorrow you move to mongodb - then you have no transaction support.

What do you do?
1) Empty method - bad because you think you have transactions but u havent
2) Create your own - then you should have some parameters that will be different that regular "startTransaction" method.

And on top of that sometimes simple interfaces just doesnt work.
Example: You need additional parameters for different implementations.

Comment: This called interface segregation principle. If you have not only transnational databases, the `transnational` method should be moved to child interface `interface trasactionalDB extends DB`. DB's that has transactions should inherit from `trasactionalDB`  and not from `DB` directly.

Comment: What's the point, i cannot use transaction in Mongo. Why botther with interface segregation principle if it doesnt help me with anything?

Comment: Mongo will implement `DB` interface directly without methods related to transactions.

Comment: My MongoDB version doesnt support transactions.

Comment: As i tried to point out in my answer, split the interfaces so that you do not have to implement the transaction function. I.E. the ITransactable interface could force the transaction function and not anything else. In this way, simply do not use the ITransactable for your mongo-db

Comment: I use the transaction in my code, if i check everywhere that is very bad.

Comment: Practically speaking, Mongo is so very different from SQL databases that you probably *won't* make this kind of switch ever. If you're trying to make your database interface *that* abstract that it could handle this kind of change, you wouldn't expose something related to transactions in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, we are hitting the wall. Removed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're exposing the concept of transactions on your interface, then you *must* functionally support transactions no matter what, since users of the interface will logically depend on it. I.e., if a caller can start a transaction, then they expect to also be able to roll back a transaction of several queries. Since Mongo doesn't natively have any concept of rolling back transactions, there's one of two possibilities:

1. You implement the possibility of rolling back queries in code, emulating the functionality of transactions for a database which doesn't natively support it. (Whether that's even reliably possible in Mongo is a debatable topic.)
2. Your interface is working at the wrong level of abstraction. If your interface is promising functionality an implementation can't deliver, then either the interface or the implementation is unrealistic.

In practice, Mongo and SQL databases are such different beasts that you would either never make this kind of change without changing large parts of your business logic around it; or you specify your interface using an extremely minimal common-denominator interface only, most certainly not exposing technology-specific concepts on an abstract interface.

Comment: Yes, correct. I am saying that interfaces doesnt  always provide what you want :)

Comment: It depends on "what you want". You certainly can define an interface that covers both Mongo and SQL databases, but it will have to be something like `storeData(data); getData(id)`; i.e. something extremely minimal. If you're trying to make an interface which covers both cars and motorbikes, it would probably have to be just `interface Vehicle`, not `interface FourWheeler`. The problem is in the details of how you use it, not in the concept of interfaces.

Comment: I want transactions, if i provide storeData i will have parameter to provide transaction support. So the problem remains whether is in "startTransaction" or storeData(data, transactionFlag)

Comment: You can't realistically cover non-transactional databases using an interface which promises transactions. *That's* your issue.

Comment: So how to cover the issue in this case ?

Comment: Define an interface that is abstract enough (does not contain details which don't work across desired implementations) to cover all possible implementations equally. In this case, don't make users think they can depend on transactions being available. If you do, they will write code which depends on transactions. If one implementation can't offer transactions, then caller code will need to cater to that case specifically and you have a leaky abstraction, which negates the point of using an interface in the first place.

Comment: I cannot define, I have storeData without and with transactions. I can't abstract more than that. The programmer should be able to use the transaction or not. It is mandatory in some cases. I cant simple call "storeData" for user registration (stores multiple tables). I should store it with transactions. In some cases i expect to have transactions  - it is mandatory for the business rules.

Comment: Then you can't have an implementation that can't provide that critical requirement; or, again, you need to replicate that requirement in code somehow.

Comment: So what is the meaning of interfaces then. From the beginning i couldnt know which methods will be provided. For example before Mongo every DB implements transactions, next year new Database will not have some implementation, how should i know that from the beginning. Everything becomes a big pile of sh1t :)

Comment: An interface can only do so much. As I posited from the beginning, you will probably never make a casual switch from Postgres to Mongo without rewriting a lot of code including a lot of assumptions. They're both databases, yes, but they're very different. Frankly, even a switch from MySQL to Postgres is not possible in practice unless you use a big abstract query builder library, or you pay very special attention to stick to a common SQL dialect. And that's just for two nominally SQL-compatible RDBMSs. No-SQL is a whole different paradigm. A single interface can't abstract that properly.

Comment: Yes i see thank you, in the end interfaces are not so magic that they write on the blogposts :)

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly correct, interfaces can be very useful, but also problematic in (fast) changing code, a best practice conserning interfaces is to keep them as small as possible.

When something can handle an transaction, create an interface only for handling an transaction. Split them up in as small as logically possible parts, in that way, when new classes emerge, you can assign them the specific interfaces that can determine their methods.

For the multiple parameter problem, this can indeed be problematic, see if you can determine if this specific value could be moved to a constructor, or indicates that the action that you are doing is indeed sightly different from the action that does not need this parameter.

I hope this helps, goodluck

Comment: Yes, I dont see any benefit when using Interfaces. If i have 5  different payments provider all of them have different parameters and logic and its more problematic.

Comment: I don't agree on that, it can be helpful to have interfaces per payment provider, in that way your methods can simply force a type that is one of the accepted payment providers. In this way, you don't care about what database you are using, you only care about the functionality. That's what is so useful about interfaces

Comment: Hm, in the real world payment providers dont agree on everything - this is only in the books. In reality one works with some payment code, the other works with something else.

Comment: True, reality is always more complicated than the book :). But you (i guess) have some method that triggers the payment, knowing the supported interface types for that item/class/something helps in determining the correct action to execute with for example a (static) switch statement

Answer (score 0):

You are right interfaces are used to add new implementations via contract but those implementations have to posses some similarity.
Let's take an example:
You cannot implement dog using human interface because dog is a living organism.
Same thing you are trying to do here.You are trying to implement a non-sql db using sql db implementation.

Comment: I don't think this is completely true, you can send messages to retrieve the same value from a non-sql db and a sql db, it depends on what is defined in the interface. But in most cases, yes, you are talking about fundamentally different things

Comment: So you are saing that everywhere in the code i should check with if statements whether the db supports transactions? Thats bad also